# C# WPF COM server E0434352 when rendering 3rd-party controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I created a class library project by converting an existing WPF windows application. The application works great - I copied the project over, and can still run it as a windows application. The class library is registered by VS 2010 as a 32-bit COM server.

Consuming the COM server in Builder C++ works a charm.  Most of the functionality in the WPF app works. However, when I attempt to render a third-party control ([Xceed's Extended WPF toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)) in the main form, I get the above-mentioned exception code ("External exception E0434352").

It is almost certainly an issue with the C# COM server not being able to find/render/reference/whatever the third-party library.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unhandled exceptions that occur in the managed code get to be hard to diagnose when they reach your C++ code.  The CLR does a reasonable job of converting the managed Exception object to a corresponding HRESULT.  But that's not working your program, 0xE0434352 is the value of the unmanaged exception that gets the CLR's exception processing code going.  Something is big-time out of whack.  Like not having the required .NET Framework version installed or an old version of the CLR already loaded in the process.  You need to document the stack trace to get help.

Comment: Hi Hans, I have in the mean time added some debugging and extra controls to C# app and got a more descriptive message out of the deal: "could not load file or assembly xceed.wpf.toolkit the system ... could not find the file specified".  It would seem that the "xceed.wpf.toolkit.dll" referenced when debugging is not available when registered as a COM server.  I am having a look at dependency walker to try and diagnose where the COM server is expecting the dll to be.  Any ideas off the bat?

Comment: It is not a COM server, Depends is useless.  The CLR just can't find it because it looks in the wrong places for the assembly.  The GAC and the directory where your EXE file is stored.  Just copying the file to that directory is a simple fix, GAC is the correct fix.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I will add to the GAC later and report back.

Comment: It was indeed the absence from the GAC that caused the problem.  Thanks for the answer.  If you create that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I would if I had some idea why the exception reporting was so lousy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I post here [@HansPassant's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366888/c-sharp-wpf-com-server-e0434352-when-rendering-3rd-party-controls#comment35793877_23366888) because it solved the OP problem and mine too.*

The CLR just can't find the 3rd-party DLL because it looks in the wrong places for the assembly: the GAC and the directory where your .exe file is stored.

Just **copying the file to the .exe directory** is a simple fix, **GAC** is the correct fix.